# Angular fill and return service var on controller call

Tags: angularjs, service, return-value

I am struggling with this for a while, and can't figure it out. What I have is main controller, factory, and service, and I'm trying to store array from service to $scope in controller. On view on item click this function in controller is triggered:

```
$scope.getSongsInPlaylist = function()
                    {
                        var playlistId = this.item.idPlayliste;                        
                        $scope.Mp3Files = songInPlaylistFactory.getSongsForPlaylist(playlistId);

                    }
```

That works ok, this function retrieves item from view and sends id of that item to function in service. 
Than in my service I have code like this:

```
var Songs = [ ];
    this.getSongsForPlaylist = function (id)
                        {
                             for (var i = 0; i < SongIsOnPlaylist.length; i++)
                             {
                                 if(SongIsOnPlaylist[i].idPlayliste == id)
                                 {                                 
                                     dataFactory.getDataById(mp3fileUrl, SongIsOnPlaylist[i].idPjesme)
                                     .success(function (data) {
                                         Songs.push(data);
                                         alert(Songs[0].naslovPjesme);//Alert one                              
                                     });                           
                                 }                            
                             }
                             alert(Songs[0]);// Alert two
                             return Songs;                         
                         }
```

dataFactory is my factory that communicates with api in backend, and that works too. var Songs is defined as: var Songs = [ ]; And SongIsOnPlaylist is filled with data.

When I trigger this, alert two gives me undefined, and alert one gives me name of first song in Songs. That means var Songs is filled with data, but when I want it to return to controller its empty ...

Am I doing something wrong here, I would appreciate any help?

Comment: Songs is out of the scope of dataFactory, you can't use that there

Comment: Songs is defined in this service, not in dataFactory if you thought on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it looks like your **dataFactory.getDataById** is async call.
Because of this what is actually happening is you returns an empty **Songs** array before it gets populated when all your async calls returns.

To solve this I would advise to use a Promise library like [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) to do something like this:

```
// note that now your service will return a promise
this.getSongsForPlaylist = function (id) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    var promises = [];
    // here in your loop just populate an array with your promises
    for (var i = 0; i < SongIsOnPlaylist.length; i++){
      if(SongIsOnPlaylist[i].idPlayliste == id){                                 
        promises.push( dataFactory.getDataById(mp3fileUrl, SongIsOnPlaylist[i].idPjesme) )
      }                            
    }
    // now use the library to resolve all promises  
    Promise.all(promises).then( function (results) {
      //HERE YOU WILL GET the results off all your async calls
      // parse the results 
      // prepare the array with songs 
      // and call
      resolve(Songs); 
    });
  });

}
```

Then you will use the service like this:

```
$scope.getSongsInPlaylist = function() {
  var playlistId = this.item.idPlayliste;                        
  songInPlaylistFactory.getSongsForPlaylist(playlistId)
  .then(function(Songs){
    $scope.Mp3Files = Songs
  })
  .error(function(err){
    //here handle any error
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you just made my day better :)